# Limitar campos do Search Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, algoritmo-de-busca

Bom dia, editei um código para um Search Box, porém quero esconder as opções que aparecem nele. No caso, quero que apareça apenas quando a busca for correspondida com as referências exatas. Não manjo de programação, este código editei com base em outras referências. Alguém pode dar uma ajuda? Obrigado!

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- FORMATAÇÃO DA PÁGINA -->
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: none;
    font-size: 10px;
 font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 10px solid #ddd;}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#myDropdown {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: -30px;
}

button {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 margin-left: 90px;
}

.dropdown-content { /* Caixa das opções de lojas */
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    max-width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown-content a { /* Opções de lojas */
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 5px;
 color: black;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: Arial;
 margin-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown a: hover {background-color: #ddd}
.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="747474">
<!-- BOTÃO PESQUISA -->
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="testbtn"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" max-width="20px" width="20px"></button>

<!-- CAIXA DE PESQUISA -->
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

<!-- CAMPOS LOJAS -->
<input type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">

<!-- SAO PAULO -->
         <a href="  ">457</a>
         <a href="  ">291</a>
         <a href="  ">441</a>
</div>
  
<!-- SCRIPT DE PESQUISA -->
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = '';
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fazer isso na mão é um pouco complicado viu, tem uma lib chamada [Selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) da uma olhada, ela vai te ajudar com isso.

Comment: Bacana, meu amigo! Não posso usar bibliotecas externas, o código vai rodar offline num sistema supervisório fechado. Por isso deixei o css e javascript dentro do mesmo.

Comment: Você pode baixar ela e deixar offline, não é um problema isso!